# angular2 emit event from dynamic child to parent

Tags: angular, components, eventemitter

I have child element in parent template. Child is added dynamically. From child I want to call parents function, which adds another child. I use `@Output` for this, it works, when child is static, but browser is unable to compile the page, when child is added dynamically:

Parent:

```
@ViewChild('dragdrophost', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  })
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

loadDragDropComponent() {        
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      DragDropComponent
    );        
    let componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);                
  }
```

Parent HTML:

```
 <div *ngIf="repair_picture" fxLayoutAlign.xs="center" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
            <!-- static works -->
            <pd-drag-drop (loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"></pd-drag-drop>
            <!-- dynamic does not works-->
            <ng-template #dragdrophost (loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"></ng-template>
        </div>
```

Child:

```
   export class DragDropComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() loadComponent = new EventEmitter<string>();
......
this.loadComponent.emit('loadComponent');
}
```

```
Compiler error:
Event binding loadComponent not emitted by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the event name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("eady shown, it is possible to dynamically load component-->
                    <ng-template #dragdrophost [ERROR ->](loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"></ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the compiler error?

Comment: @AbelValdez error shared above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are dynamically creating the component, you need to wire up any activities to pass the inputs and listen to the outputs. To wire up the output in your case, you'll just need another line to wire up listening to the event:

```js
loadDragDropComponent() {        
  let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
    DragDropComponent
  );

  let componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  componentRef.instance.loadComponent.subscribe($event => {
    this.loadDragDropComponent($event)
  });
}
```

You'll also need to remove that stuff in your template that is wiring up the listener since that isn't valid (i.e. `(loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"`).

Comment: What if the component is created using `createEmbeddedView()`? because in this case, we will not componentRef.instance?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass some callback function inside your new component.

```
let componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
componentRef.instance.loadComponent = function() {
    // put your code here
}
```

And then you can call your callback inside component

```
this.loadComponent();
```

Comment: This is not using `@Output`s and emitting events.

Comment: The problem is, that it is even not possible to compile the code, when I use it like this:
  `code` <ng-template #dragdrophost (loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"></ng-template> `code`
The error:
Event binding loadComponent not emitted by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the event name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("eady shown, it is possible to dynamically load component-->
                    <ng-template #dragdrophost [ERROR ->](loadComponent)="loadDragDropComponent($event)"></ng-template>

Comment: @niio when you dinamically creating component, which is inside 'entryComponents', you doesn't have some stuff, like onInit hook, Input, Output. Even in ngx-bootstrap modals you need to pass all this stuff using modalInstance inside .content, and not Input and decoratore.

Comment: @niio and to use my method you need to remove from tempate (loadComponent) event and add loadComponent method definition inside child component class. Also you may need to use .bind() function, if you are calling some methods or props from parent class